# android application takes too long to open o real device, in emulator runs fine

Tags: android, performance, installation, device

The app I'm developing works with no problem on emulator, but when I install the debug apk on a device, it takes 30 secs or maybe a minute to open for the first time (white screen for the entire time), and when finally it shows something and the app runs, it first shows me an error that the app takes too long, I choose to ignore it since the app finally show something. When it finally works for the first time, it runs with no problem at all. This only happened THE FIRST TIME the app is opened after installation.

So in summary:

1. The app works great on emulator.
2. The app is installed with no problem.
3. The first time the app is opened it shows nothing but a full white screen.
4. The app finally works just like in the emulator.
5. Shortly after the app starts working, the device shows me an error, to close or wait for the app.
6. After ignoring the error, the app works with no problem at all, all services working.
7. If the app is closed and opened again, it works perfectly.

Note: This app have multiDexEnabled true, I know this may be the cause, but in the emulator works fine.

Thanks for all the help you can give me here.

EDIT:
Some more infor about the app:
It uses maps, and firebae to give user notifications.
The map service and activity is called only when the user enters the activity, firebase service on the other hand, is called when the app runs. 
this is the gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.andres.redfutbol"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'



    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please if you need more information let me know.
And i dont think this is a dublicate question as suggested below, other questions like this one is about the emulator, and as i mentioned before, in my case, my app runs fast and good in the emulator, is when i tested it in a real device when this problem happened, and to mention it again, it only happened THE FIRST TIME the app is opened after installation, later, i can close it, open it and close it again, it will work fine.

Edit as suggested:

This is the first activity and method:

```
public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editTextUser;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    private String mi_token;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);
        editTextUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUser);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    }
```

As asked by Julius, here are the custom classes and the layout for the first activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.andres.redfutbol.LogInActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ingresa Correo y Password"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextUser"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextUser"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ingresar"
        android:id="@+id/buttonIngresar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="fnc_LogIn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nuevo Usuario"
        android:id="@+id/buttonNuevoUsuario"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonIngresar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:onClick="fnc_NewUser" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your launcher activity (first activity to open).

Comment: Thanks for your response, i edited the post and put that in

Comment: What does logcat say when you run the app on your phone?

Comment: Is there a custom Application class you use? In case there is post that one, plus xml of activity you posted.

Comment: i dont have a logcat from my phone because im running it as a debuged apk not from the usb connection. I´ll try to do it that way to get the logcat

Comment: The custom application classes in my app are not called in the first activity.     If you need them i´ll post them too,

Comment: My theory is that something heavy is called early in app lifecycle. First activity and xml doesn't show any long loading code. Application class is called first, if you have custom class for Application onCreate might contain cause of lag.

Comment: i see, let me take a look at that and keep updating this. Thanks for your help

Comment: I checked and i dont have any class with the  extends Application to have a custom Application class.

Comment: How about the parts of the manifest defining the application and launcher activity, and any other lifecycle events from the startup activity, `onResume`, `onStart` etc.  Looks like `onCreate` barely does anything - not clear what would take so long.